# Add different background image to menu item within ul li

Tags: menu

I have a menu within a ul li and I'd like to change the background image for only one of the menu items.

In the css below the current background image is menu-ul.jpg and I need the additional background image for the "Capsules" menu item to be menu-ul2.jpg

Here's my current menu html:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="index.htm"><strong>home</strong><span></span></a></li>
<li><a href="products.htm"><strong>Products</strong><span></span></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="dew_drops.htm">Dew Drops</a></li>
<li><a href="capsules.htm">Capsules</a></li>
<li><a href="salvation_balm.htm">Salvation Balm</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the piece of css that deals with the background image for the menu items:

```
.menu ul {
position:       absolute;
padding:        -3px 10px;
top:            -999em;
width:          107px;
background:     url(../images/menu-ul.jpg) left top repeat;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...thanks.

Meg

Answer (score 0):

You can reach that effect by adding a class to the list item you want to change.

Add this to your CSS

```
.menu ul li.capsule {
 background:     url(../images/menu-ul2.jpg)
}
```

And this in your html

```
<li class="capsule"><a href="capsules.htm">Capsules</a></li>
```

Off course there are many other ways...